# query for median with case statement

Tags: postgresql

How to get the `median` of the `val`column from table `test` whose value is greater than 20.

```
id        val
1         5.43
2         106.26 
3         14.00 
4         39.58
5         27.00
```

In this case output would be median(27.00, 39.58, 106.26) = 39.58.

I am using PostgreSQL database.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From PostgreSQL 9.4 you use [ordered aggregates](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html):

```
postgres=# SELECT percentile_cont(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY val) 
              FROM foo WHERE val > 20;
┌─────────────────┐
│ percentile_cont │
╞═════════════════╡
│           39.58 │
└─────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

or some really modern syntax:

```
postgres=# SELECT percentile_cont(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY val) 
                                       FILTER (WHERE val > 20)
              FROM foo;
┌─────────────────┐
│ percentile_cont │
╞═════════════════╡
│           39.58 │
└─────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can we write a query using `case` instead of where clause . The reason why i am asking this is , For some set of value i have to perform `SUM` and for some set of value `AVG` and `MEDIAN`.

Comment: I didn't notice the `FILTER` keyword you used in the second query i think that will work perfectly. Thanks again.